# Create a child page using ruby in confluence

Tags: ruby, confluence

I want to create a new page in the confluence wiki by using a ruby script. This script will run once a month and everytime create a new page. I know how to create a new page but I can't tell confluence that the created page should be a child page of another one. Here's what I tried:

```
server = Confluence::Server.new(url)
server.login(confluence['username'], confluence['password'])

template = load_file(template_filename)
erb = ERB.new(template)
page = {
  "space" => "lxeng",
  "title" => "Release 2015.08",
  "ancestors" => [{"id" => 49776851 }],
  "content" => erb.result,
}
server.storePage(page)
```

The code above works perfectly. It just doesn't create the page under the page with the ID **49776851**.
I know that you can use **the ancestors** in other languages but i can't figure out how it works in ruby. How can I tell where the new page should be placed?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have not heard of confluence, but have you tried using a gem?

Comment: @HunterStevens no I haven't tried this because I don't know anything about gem. How do you mean "using a gem"?

Comment: Gems are libraries that come with classes, methods, modules, and at times their own DSL. I do not know what confluence is, but I am sure someone has made a gem (or an API, if you will) to interact with it. [rubygems search for confluence](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=confluence)

Comment: @HunterStevens many thanks for this. I'll see if I find a library to solve my problem.